# error C2855: command-line option '-Zc:__cplusplus' and '-Zc:referenceBinding' inconsistent with precompiled header

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

We have a Qt project on VS. We are using PCH files. From October 11 compilator started to show errors:

```
c:\work\repos\... : error C2855: command-line option '/Zc:__cplusplus' inconsistent with precompiled header
1>c:\work\repos\... : error C2855: command-line option '/Zc:referenceBinding' inconsistent with precompiled header
```

Removing `'/Zc:__cplusplus`' and `/Zc:referenceBinding` options from project configuration solve the issue, but I wanna keep them. Did anybody face such a problem?
Pushed the code back a year, can observe the same error (so it's not an impact) Why it stopped working?

OS Win10, Qt 5.14.1, VS 2017 (last updated version)

P.S. Did a small and simple test VS console projects, putting this `'/Zc:__cplusplus`' and `/Zc:referenceBinding` params and everything works fine

Comment: Have you got the same options on the file that builds the pre-compiled header (usually `pch.cpp` but does not have to be) as well as the main project options ?

Comment: Yes, I changed my build log details to Detailed and see, that stdafx.cpp is building with these 2 options.
Moreover, there is no problem on our Jenkins job, but 3 dev can observe these errors on their local machines

Comment: Make sure to do a clean build as changes to project options do no force a full rebuild.